# Regex expression to filter html attributes issues with conditions ">"

Tags: c#, html, regex, vue.js

My goal is to obtain a regex expression that can get the attribute names and attribute values of pretty much any `html` tag.
I'm currently using vuejs (which is the part that is making this tricky) and I'm having issues when the `> char` appears on conditions for example.

My current regex expression: `(\S+)=["]?((?:.(?!["]?\s+(?:\s+)=|[>"]))+.)["]?`

My string example:

```
<input type="text"
    class="form-control component-input-style"
    v-if="(!valueType || (valueType == 'email' || valueType == 'phone'))"
    v-model="currentValue"
    v-attr="data-min-length: minLength, data-max-length: maxLength, data-integer-only: integerOnly"
    v-class="disabled: disabled"
    size="{{ value && value > 10 ? value.length : 10 }}"
    v-on="keyup: detectKeystroke, keypress: filterValues, blur: onBlur, focus: onFocus">
```

What happens is that when the expression reaches the "`size="{{ value && value > 10 ? value.length : 10 }}`" it assumes that the `>` `char` is closing the tag when its not...

Does anyone find a fix for this regular expression?

thanks.

Comment: Good reading - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/

Comment: While [RegEx match open tags ...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348) is fun to read, it doesn't actually explain the problem or how to solve it. You want [How to use the HTML Agility Pack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/846994/).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use HTML Agility pack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/846994/how-to-use-html-agility-pack)